# How to pass parameter with javascript function using OnClientPopup of ajax dropdownextender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm developing an web user control using `Ajax:dropdownextendeer` and `asp:controls`.

I need to run a java-script function when user clicks on arrow of `dropdownextender`.

For that `Ajax:dropdownextendeer` provides an event `OnClientPopup`.

But this supports no parameters.I need to run a function that needs some parameters.

Is there any way to send parameters with `OnClientPopup` of `Ajax:dropdownextendeer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution for this problem.`Ajax:dropdownextender` doesn't support any parameters in java-script function on `OnClientPopup`.But we can pass parameters in java-script.Just add function on page load.

### Ex.-

```
string func = "function docall(){showDataCombo('" + txtDisplay.ClientID
            + "','" + divGrid.ClientID
            + "','" + Table1.ClientID
            + "','" + txtSearch.ClientID
            + "','" + hfScrollPosition.ClientID
            + "','" + gridEdit.ClientID
            + "','" + lblTot.ClientID
            + "','" + Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID
            + "','" + divComboContainer.ClientID
            + "','" + DropPanel.ClientID + "');}";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "CallJS", func, true);
        DDE.OnClientPopup = func;
```

Just create a function string without any parameters and call your java-script function in that.And assign this new function string on `OnClientPouup` event of `Ajax-drop-downextender`.
And it works fine for me.